# Batch crashes after goto

Tags: batch-file, cmd, crash

I have the problem of my batch file closing after entering the letter "k" as %Grundn% at the part ":negativ"

**It seems I have a syntax error on an echo somewhere here:**

```
echo.
echo Vielen Dank fuer Ihre Nachricht.
echo.
if %Begruendung% == Angaben echo Um Ihre Anfrage zeitnah zu bearbeiten, bitten wir noch um einige Angaben.
if %Begruendung% == Ansprechpartner echo Leider sind wir für Ihre Anfrage nicht der richtige Ansprechpartner.
```

Some words are german but that shouldn't matter.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Here's the complete code:

```
@echo off


::-------------ANREDE-------------
set /p Anrede=Herr (h) oder Frau (f) ?
if %Anrede% == h set Geschlecht=Herr
if %Anrede% == f set Geschlecht=Frau

::NAME
set /p Name=Name?


::-------------GRUND-------------
:: set /p Grund=Bestellung (b) oder Anfrage (a) ?
:: if %Grund% == b set Dank=Bestellung
:: if %Grund% == a set Dank=Anfrage


::-------------ZUSTAND-------------
set /p Zustand=positive Antwort (p) / negative Antwort (n)

if %Zustand% == p goto positiv
if %Zustand% == n goto negativ

:positiv
echo positiver Test
goto ausgabe

:negativ
::Grund
set /p Grundn=brauchen noch Angaben (b) / koennen nicht helfen (k)
if %Grundn% == b set Begruendung=Angaben
if %Grundn% == k set Begruendung=Ansprechpartner

if %Grundn% == k goto schluss

::Grund-Angaben
set /p Grundna=Typenschild, Seriennummer (t) / Artikelnummer (l)
if %Grundna% == t set Nachfrage=Typenschild
if %Grundna% == l set Nachfrage=Artikelnummer


:schluss
::-------------AUSGABE-------------
echo.
echo.
if %Geschlecht% == Herr echo Sehr geehrter Herr %Name%
if %Geschlecht% == Frau echo Sehr geehrte Frau %Name%
echo.
echo Vielen Dank fuer Ihre Nachricht.
echo.
if %Begruendung% == Angaben echo Um Ihre Anfrage zeitnah zu bearbeiten, bitten wir noch um einige Angaben.
if %Begruendung% == Ansprechpartner echo Leider sind wir für Ihre Anfrage nicht der richtige Ansprechpartner.
if %Nachfrage% == Typenschild echo Bitte senden Sie uns ein Foto des Typenschilds oder teilen uns die richtige Seriennummer mit,
if %Nachfrage% == Typenschild echo damit wir Ihren Motor zweifelsfrei zuordnen und die entsprechenden Abklaerungen treffen koennen.
if %Nachfrage% == Artikelnummer echo Leider ist die von Ihnen angegebene Nummer in unserem System nicht ersichtlich. Bitte pruefen Sie die Nummer und geben uns Bescheid.


::-------------NOTIZEN-------------
::Ausgabe in Zwischenablage kopieren: if %Geschlecht% == Herr echo Sehr geehrter Herr %Name% | clip
:ende

echo.
echo.
pause
```

Comment: Don't use `Set /P`, when you're looking for known responses, use `Choice` instead. For information on the command, enter `Choice /?` at the command prompt, and read it's syntax, options and usage.

Comment: Learn how to [debug batch files](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_debugging.php)! Open a command prompt window and run the script from there by typing its path (within quotes), or by changing to the parent directory ([`cd /D`](http://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)) and then typing the name of the script...

Comment: Thank you aschipfl that made it easier to narrow down where the problem is, but I still can't yet figure it out: it seems I have a syntax error.
I highlighted it in the original post above.
Any ideas?

Comment: Should be pretty obvious if you are following your logic when selecting **k**. You skip over the code that assigns a value to the variable `Nachfrage`. Because the variable is not defined, the `IF` command syntax is invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was really confused with German language, so please notify if I have done something wrong in the code I am providing:

```bat
@echo off

rem -------------ANREDE-------------
choice /c:fh /n /m "Anrede=Herr (h) oder Frau (f)? "
if errorlevel 1 set "Geschlecht=Frau"
if errorlevel 2 set "Geschlecht=Herr"

rem NAME
set /p Name=Name? 

rem -------------GRUND-------------
choice /c:ab /n /m "Bestellung (b) oder Anfrage (a) ? "
if errorlevel 1 set "Dank=Anfrage"
if errorlevel 2 set "Dank=Bestellung"

rem -------------ZUSTAND-------------
choice /c:np /n /m "positive Antwort (p) / negative Antwort (n) "
if errorlevel 1 goto negativ
if errorlevel 2 goto positiv

:positiv
echo positiver Test
goto ausgabe

:negativ
rem Grund
choice /c:kb /n /m "brauchen noch Angaben (b) / koennen nicht helfen (k) "
if errorlevel 1 set "Begruendung=Ansprechpartner" && goto schluss
if errorlevel 2 set "Begruendung=Angaben"

rem Grund-Angaben
choice /c:lt /n /m "Typenschild, Seriennummer (t) / Artikelnummer (l) "
if errorlevel 1 set "Nachfrage=Artikelnummer"
if errorlevel 2 set "Nachfrage=Typenschild"

:schluss
rem -------------AUSGABE-------------
echo. && echo.
if "%Geschlecht%" == "Herr" echo Sehr geehrter Herr %Name%
if "%Geschlecht%" == "Frau" echo Sehr geehrte Frau %Name%
echo.
echo Vielen Dank fuer Ihre Nachricht.
echo.
if "%Begruendung%" == "Angaben" echo Um Ihre Anfrage zeitnah zu bearbeiten, bitten wir noch um einige Angaben.
if "%Begruendung%" == "Ansprechpartner" echo Leider sind wir fur Ihre Anfrage nicht der richtige Ansprechpartner.
if "%Nachfrage%" == "Typenschild" echo Bitte senden Sie uns ein Foto des Typenschilds oder teilen uns die richtige Seriennummer mit,
if "%Nachfrage%" == "Typenschild" echo damit wir Ihren Motor zweifelsfrei zuordnen und die entsprechenden Abklaerungen treffen koennen.
if "%Nachfrage%" == "Artikelnummer" echo Leider ist die von Ihnen angegebene Nummer in unserem System nicht ersichtlich. Bitte pruefen Sie die Nummer und geben uns Bescheid.

rem -------------NOTIZEN-------------
rem Ausgabe in Zwischenablage kopieren: if "%Geschlecht%" == "Herr" echo Sehr geehrter Herr %Name% | clip
:ende

echo. && echo.
pause

:ausgabe
rem [your code here]
```

Added choice and rem instead of `::`. Also, double-quote strings in `if` statements.